# Inserting line to a file before a given line number

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a list of line number for a given file. Now I want to insert a specific line before each of these lines in the file. How is it possible to do using C++ file operations.

I know that `tellg()` would give location of character in file, but how do I get the line and print just before that line.

Comment: If you want to do this without writing an intermediate file then you need to copy all of the content following the location at which you want to insert the line by a distance of the size of the content you want to insert. (You can't just insert data in the middle of a file as a simple operation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineNo` is a vector containing points before where insertion needs to take place sorted in  ascending order.

```
line =1
while(std::getline(myReadFile, s1)){
                if(line == lineNo[0]-1){
                        opfile<<line<<":"<<s1<<"\n";
                        opfile<<"what ever I want to insert\n";
                        lineNo.erase(lineNo.begin());
                }   
                else{
                        opfile<<line<<":"<<s1<<"\n";
                }   
                line++;
        }
```

Now delete the old file and rename the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way is to:

1. open a new file,
2. copy the contents of the original file up to the insertion point,
3. insert the new content into the new file opened in step 1,
4. copy the rest of the contents of the original file after the insertion point,
5. delete the original file,
6. rename the file opened in step 1 with the name of the original file.

Alternatively, you can:

1. find the insertion point in your target file,
2. remember this point in target file,
3. open a temporary file,
4. copy the remaining contents of target file into your temporary file (that is, copy everything in the target file after the insertion point to the temporary file),
5. seek to the insertion point in target file,
6. write into the target file the information you want to insert,
7. write the contents of the temporary file into target file,
8. delete temporary file if your technology will not auto delete the temp file for you.

Note: If you have line numbers, then it is best that you start with the max line number and work your way to the minimum line number, as the line numbers will be changing after you start inserting the new content into the file. By starting at the max value and working your way to the minimum, inserting content behind the items waiting to be worked on means their line numbers stay valid throughout the entire operation.

Comment: I think i found a simpler way. Check the answer